# Screen door track replacement

Tags: doors, backyard, screens, mosquitoes

I need to replace the twin plastic tracks (see pic below) guiding the tops of two sliding mesh screen doors attached to the back entrance of my house. The tracks are plastic and come in one piece, but one track (green arrow) is slightly (~0.5in) higher than the other (blue arrow). The higher track is breaking apart (red arrow) causing the door sliding on that track to dislocate when sliding. The replacement looks easy if I can buy this type of twin tracks somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it online, maybe because I don't know the right keywords to search for. Does anyone know the name of this type of twin tracks?

[image: The tracks]

Answer (score 1):

Sliding screen door "tracks" are not some generic part that you can replace willy-nilly. They are a *part of* the entire sliding glass door frame assembly. Unless you can find the original manufacturer of your door unit (unlikely) and get just a part of the frame assembly (very unlikely) then you wont be able to replace that.

> The replacement looks easy

**Wrong**

Even if you could buy the OEM upper frame piece (very unlikely), replacement would involve very intrusive work including removal of all glass doors and panels and separation of the frame from the plaster/stucco/trim etc.

You need to pursue a **repair** path, which can be complex in its own right. IMO repairing your existing track is your only option.

[image]

Comment: The replacement *is* easy if I get the track. These are not glass doors, but screen doors, which I thought was clear enough. I have edited the question to now explicitly say "mesh".

Comment: The screen door track is typically **part of** the glass door track, not a seperate piece. If yours was purchased and installed as a stand-alone unit, that would be unusual, but you should have luck finding/ordering parts like this at a door and window shop.

Comment: Yeah, mine is separate. In fact, I don't have a sliding glass door - I have French doors and then a sliding mesh screen, which slides on the track in my pic. The track is just screwed on to the door frame. I've been searching online for the same kind of track, but no luck so far. I may just have to buy new mesh screens (of the same height) that don't require this special twin track.